# Starting a service yields "This account is currently not available." on FreeBSD

Tags: java, freebsd, jenkins

In this case I'm trying to start Jenkins as a service on FreeBSD 8.3. I recently upgraded my Jenkins installation from 1.476 to 1.554 using pkgng. I haven't used the previous installation, so (as far as I know) the service was never started before.

This is what I do (and get):

```
$ sudo /usr/local/etc/rc.d/jenkins start
>> Starting jenkins.
>> This account is currently not available.
$
```

I already located the jenkins user on my system. So it's present. And I checked if if the jenkins_user is overridden in the /etc/rc.conf or the /etc/defaults/rc.conf file, and it's not. The user "jenkins" should be the user it starts as according to the following lines in /usr/local/etc/rc.d/jenkins:

```
: ${jenkins_user="jenkins"}
: ${jenkins_group="jenkins"}
```

I would like to know what the problem is. Hope someone can help me. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the old jenkins user had `/usr/sbin/nologin` as shell. Which needs to be something like `/bin/sh` or `/usr/local/bin/bash`. I did a manual removal of the user and the jenkins package and then after a re-install it finally "worked". And I noticed the significant change in the user shell.

I get other errors now, but at least I can see them in my logs (`/var/log/jenkins.log`). And the dreaded "This account is currently not available." message is gone.